# @GeneratedValue Neo4j-OGM ClassCastException

Tags: neo4j, sessionfactory, neo4j-ogm

When trying to create a new Object using Neo4j OGM session (session.save(o)), I get the following error:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74 cannot be cast to org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue
        at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.ClassInfo.isPrimaryIndexField(ClassInfo.java:855)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.ClassInfo.getFieldInfos(ClassInfo.java:349)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.ClassInfo.primaryIndexField(ClassInfo.java:824)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo.finish(DomainInfo.java:185)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo.create(DomainInfo.java:94)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MetaData.<init>(MetaData.java:42)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:106)
        at com.wko.dpifyV1.server.Neo4jSessionFactoryV1.getNeo4jSession(Neo4jSessionFactoryV1.java:63)
        at com.wko.dpifyV1.server.GenericService.<init>(GenericService.java:11)
        at com.wko.dpifyV1.server.PersonServiceImpl.<init>(PersonServiceImpl.java:7)
        at com.wko.dpifyV1.server.Neo4jServiceImpl.sayHello(Neo4jServiceImpl.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using Neo4j-ogm-3.0.1 (api,core,boltdriver). I follow the basic guide (https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:session).
This is my testClass

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;

@NodeEntity
public class TestClass {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
       public TestClass(String name) {
          this.name = name;
       }

}
```

This is my session:

```
public Session getNeo4jSession() {
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.basic("***", "***"));
        org.neo4j.ogm.driver.Driver ogmDriver = new BoltDriver(driver);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(ogmDriver, "com.client.model");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
return session;
}
```

So yeah... As the factory scans (using https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner) I get this error.

Comment: Cannot find anything in your code that might cause this problem. The only thing I could imagine is that your GWT application uses some kind of dependency injection and (as the error message points out) creates a proxy for your domain. (Just to be safe in the long run: Provide an empty constructor in your domain class for constructing the objects when loading. (https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:node-entity first paragraph) )

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I'll give that a shot later today and most of my objects have the empty constructor, as in the guide. Now I admit I clearly forgot it in this TestClass.
There shouldn't be an issue with dependency injection because I got al the jar files in the project. I don't know why I get proxies but will have a deeper look. I'll get back to you.

Comment: I found a way that everything works just fine... Whilst reading the manual again, I went to have a look at the abstract class DomainObject. Whilst looking I looked at the following: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/tree/master/test/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/domain
I created a test package with Entity, Movie, Rating and Person. As you can see the abstract class is very basic. **No annotations** Could that have been the issue? Because I annotated an abstract class?
Now I don't use the annotation and it takes the Id by default. If I can confirm the error and why I'll post it. Thanks!!

Comment: I also tested pure OGM usage with an abstract class annotated with `Id` and `GeneratedValue` on the `id` field and an implementation annotated with `NodeEntity`. It works without any problems. It seems very likely that it is caused by GWT that creates a proxy object.

Comment: You pushed me in the right direction. I'm now reading http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html
That proxy object seems to be the issue. This article seems to be the solution at first sight. Will give an update.
Your help is much appreciated @meistermeier

Comment: I got it to work. Changed RPC to RequestFactory but the initial problem had to be between GWT and OGM. I created a domain without annotations, went down to OGM 2.1.1 (Following Baeldung example).
I have to admit that I can't put my finger on the reason why exactly it goes crazy on the annotations.